# Why would .htaccess fire twice in IE when downloading a protected XLS file?

Tags: apache, excel, .htaccess

Certain directories are protected by Basic Auth using a .htaccess file on an older Apache 1.x server. Today a user pointed out that the username/password was requested twice for the file he had just posted - once when entering the directory to see the index, and then AGAIN when downloading the file. Finding this odd, I researched the usual problems with double-firing .htaccess authentication:

- server name (http://server vs. http://www.server)
- trailing slash (http://server/somedir vs. http://server/somedir/)
- http vs https

No luck. Add to the confusion that Firefox/Chrome/Safari don't ask twice - only IE (6 and 7). Further investigation showed that this doesn't happen with PDF files - only Excel files - even blank ones.

Is Excel calling back to the server somehow that requires a second authentication? Why does it only happen in IE?

Not critical - but I'm very curious what could be causing this.

EDIT - I think bmdhacks nailed it. Watching the network traffic, Excel+IE fires back a second request with a different User Agent called "Microsoft Protocol Discovery"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Excel, but Windows Media Player has a special interaction with IE where when IE requests a file with a MIME type that Windows Media Player owns, instead of handing the downloaded file over to WMP, it instructs Windows Media Player to download the file itself.  This could result in requesting the file twice, once for IE to ask for the file, and a second time when WMP downloads it.

It's possible that Microsoft uses this mechanism in other products like Excel too.  You might be able to discover this by looking at the User-Agent header submitted in the second request.  In the Windows Media case, it actually changes from IE to WMP's User-Agent on the second request.